# Print empty string with double quotes instead of single quotes in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list I want to pretty print that contains empty lists as well as lists with string members. the problem is that lists that contains strings are printed with double quotes:

> >>>str(['a'])
>   
> "['a']"

But an empty list is printed with single quotes:

> >>> str([])
>   
> '[]'

Is there a way to always force printing string with double quotes ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the representation of the object being printed; if the string to print contains the `\"` character, then a single quote will be used; if the string contains the `\'` character, then a double quote will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom string formatting:

```
print '"{}"'.format(str([]))
```

prints

```
"[]"
```

This won't affect strings nested in containers, though:

```
print '"{}"'.format(str(["a"]))
```

prints

```
"['a']"
```