# Represent List as a String with Double-Quotes Instead of Single-Quotes for JSON

Tags: python, json, string-formatting

Input:

```
mylist = ["a", "b"]
```

I have to output:

```
'["a", "b"]'
```

But using `str(mylist)` or `'{}'.format(mylist)` on the list gets me:

```
"['a', 'b']"
```

This is for a JSON API, and JSON doesn't accept `'`.

Looking around, this is indeed stated that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954687/print-empty-string-with-double-quotes-instead-of-single-quotes-in-python) it doesn't work with format for containers.

Is there still a solution? I'm now using `.replace("'", '"')` but that really seems silly.

Comment: What version of python do you use? I get `['a', 'b']` if I just print `mylist` using python2.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: yes, and that's not what they want.

Comment: Ohh, I did not understand the question correctly – my bad.

Comment: You'll get single our double quotes depending on the contents of the string. Try `['a"', "b'"]` for example. **Why** do you want to do this? You most likely do not want to rely on the implementation detail of a debugging feature.

Comment: You need to understand the basic Python syntax. This is a VERY easy question.

Comment: @PythonGuy: is it really? This has little to do with Python syntax, not directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think this is a homework question, and it requires him to output that kind of output. He doesn't understand single quotes are the same as double quotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to do this because I guess I'm trying to send a JSON Array/List as parameter in an API call (and it doesn't work with the standard single quotes).

Comment: @PythonGuy: I suspect it's actually a JSON API, not a homework question. JSON doesn't like single-quotes.

Comment: @Will Oh, k. He should have stated that in the question tho.

Comment: @PythonGuy You have quite a hostile attitude. How would I be a beginner? You're the 11 year old. (This comment now doesn't make much sense after he threw away the discussion on his multiply downvoted answer).

Comment: @PascalvKooten BTW, I *AM* an 11 year old. Seriously. But let's not get off topic. How do I have a hostile attitude? I don't understand.

Comment: @PythonGuy No I am the 11 year old!

Comment: @PascalvKooten I thought you were a beginner, because I didn't know it was a JSON. Sorry.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's noon right now.

Comment: @PythonGuy, ok afternoon nap then ;)

Comment: Let's move this to a discussion (lol).

Comment: @PascalvKooten K, :).

Comment: @PythonGuy: Indeed! I have edited the question and added the `json` tag and to the title, and some additional clarity. These details are important, and this should be a learning experience, but, I must agree that you were a bit hostile. It's not a good idea to just assume the user is stupid or unaware of basic syntax--there are often just details missing. Missing details might be a good thing to be mad about, but if you're going to be aggressive, at least be aggressive about the right thing. We should all just delete these flamey comments and put it to rest. No hard feelings! :)

Comment: @PythonGuy: it doesn't matter if something is homework. But until the edit just now the question was just unclear and incomplete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Think you tagged the wrong person there. It was a clear question, Simeon gave the answer before this whole discussion started. I gave a clear input, and a clear output expectation, a lead on another discussion. True, my reasons weren't there, but they are not always required.

Comment: @Will I wasn't trying to be hostile, but thx for the pointer. :D Let's stop the flamewarz now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to output JSON? In that case you should use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
import json
json.dumps(mylist)
```

This outputs: `'["a", "b"]'`.

Comment: I guess you could indeed call it a JSON list/array that I'm trying to output.